# File reads but doesn't write to this "database"

Tags: java, file

I have a file named AccountDetails.txt, what I am trying to do is scan the data in this file and replace the balance.

It used to work fine on my Unix laptop but it doesn't write to the text file on my Windows PC.
I made sure the text file is not read-only

```
public void removeFromBalance(String username, long amount) {


        String tempFile = "temp.txt";
        File oldfile = new File(directory, fileName);
        File newFile = new File(directory, tempFile);

        String userName = "";
        String balance = "";

        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            Scanner x = new Scanner(oldfile);

            x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

            while (x.hasNext()) {

                userName = x.next();
                balance = x.next();

                if (userName.equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {

                    long result = Long.parseLong(balance) - amount;
                    pw.println(userName + "," + result);

                } else {
                    pw.println(userName + "," + balance);
                }
            }

            x.close();
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            oldfile.delete();
            File dump = new File(fileName);
            newFile.renameTo(dump);


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the underlying platform's character encoding. Scanner can specify the charset, FileWriter is a too old utility class.

```
public void removeFromBalance(String username, long amount) throws IOException {

    String tempFile = "temp.txt";
    Path oldfile = Paths.get(directory.toString(), fileName);
    File newFile = oldfile.resolveSibling(tempFile);

    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(
                Files.newBufferedWriter(newfile, charset,
                    StandardOpenOptions.APPEND, StandardOpenOptions.CREATE));
            Files.lines(oldfile)) {
                .map(line -> line.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
                .filter(xx -> xx.length >= 2)
                .map(xx -> {
                    String userName = xx[0];
                    String balance = xx[1];
                    if (userName.equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
                        long result = Long.parseLong(balance) - amount;
                        pw.println(userName + "," + result);
                    } else {
                        pw.println(userName + "," + balance);
                    }
                });
    }
    Files.delete(oldfile);
    Files.move(newFile, oldfile); // Or ...
```

Files.lines defaults to UTF-8. Try-with-resources closes both files too, `Files.move` can have a REPLACE_EXISTING too, but I do not think you intended to *replace* the old file.

Answer (score 0):

> it used to work fine on my unix laptop but it doesn't write to the txt file on my windows PC i made sure the txt file is not read-only

You're using `\n` (Line Feed) as a delimiter, which is fine for Linux, but on Windows the default line delimiter uses two characters - `\r\n` (Carriage Return + Line Feed).

If your text file was created on windows, you need to take it into account and use `\r\n`

Comment: modified to :
x.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]");
still same result

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.    When you say "it doesn't write", what do you mean?   Does it fail?  Is the file created but empty?   Could it be being created somewhere other than you think it is?  Does it throw an exception?

Also, you say you changed your x.useDelimiter - that's  your read side, which you say works.  How do you know it worked? 

Finally, reduce this to its essentials.   You say the problem is the write side: strip it down so all you're doing is opening a file and writing known contents and then closing.   Prove to yourself that that's where your problem is.